# PrimeNG datatable. Add new row in group in rows

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using datatable control from PrimeNG Angular2.
I attempt to add a new row in table that's grouped by some data.

The row group header with the button.

```
    <template pTemplate="rowgroupheader" let-rowData>
        {{rowData['SectionTitle']}}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="addNewRow(1)" style="float: right">+</button>
    </template>
```

function for row adding

```
   addNewRow(sectionId: number) {
        let item = new Register10SectionViewModel();
        item.SectionTitle = "";
        item.SectionId = sectionId;
        item.AssetType = null;
        item.CauseDisposal = null;
        item.Num1 = 0;
        item.Num2 = 0;
        item.Num3 = 0;
        item.Num4 = 0;

        this.model.Register10Data.push(item);
    }
```

The string is added but not in the group but in the end of the data table. Apparently I have to redraw the table. But how to do it? As I understand this component should be able to do it itself. Please reply if someone used this component.
[image: The data table component]